# WordPress: How does one get the date of an attachment?

Tags: wordpress, date, attachment

I have no idea how to get the date of attachments. I acquire the attachments as follows:

```
$attachments = get_children(array('post_parent'=>$post->ID, 'post_type'=>'attachment', 'post_mime_type'=>'image'));

foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
    //I want to get the date of the attachment
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks for looking!

Comment: I don't have a copy of WP running to play with, but have you tried [wp_get_attachment_metadata](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_metadata)? I don't even know what it returns, but it seems to me that it might contain an upload date.

Comment: if you `print_r($attachment)` does it not have a field with the publish date in it?  If so you'd `echo `$attachment->pub_date` or whatever the name of the variable is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Attachment is a type of post, a Custom Post Type at the end of the day. As so, they share exactly the same table and characteristics as other post types.

It's just a matter of:

```
foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
    echo $attachment->post_title . ' - ' . $attachment->post_date;
}
```

If you need specific attachments metadata, they have specialized functions, like [`wp_get_attachment_metadata`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_metadata) as suggested by @brbcoding in comments.